# CString to Edit Control in MFC

Tags: c++, vector, mfc, cstring

So i'm retrieving so data from a .txt file to a myclass (class), including

```
public:
vector<int> ID
vector<string> name
vector<string> add
```

but when i try to access them to show them in an edit box in a MFC dlg it just returns me this to the box:

```
ID: 1
Name: (jibberish)
address: (jiberish)
ID: 2
Name: (jibberish)
address: (jiberish)
etc...
```

code used in the edit control box in a for cycle

```
int s1;    
CString s2, s3;
s1.Format(_T("\r\nID: %d"),myclass.ID[i]);
s2.Format(_T("\r\nName: %s"),myclass.name[i]);
s3.Format(_T("\r\nAddress: %s"),myclass.add[i]);
Edi_box += s1 + s2 + s3;
```

so it reads the vector of integers but not the vector of strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `_T` macro will create a wchar_t string or a char string, depending on the charset settings of the VS project. In order to format a `std::string` (which is char-based) into one of those, you have to use the right conversion. Microsoft ships an extension to the "normal" `printf()`-style syntax that is supported by many functions: Use the `%ls` to insert a wchar_t string and `%hs` for a char string.

Notes:

- The conversion from wchar_t to char can fail, so don't expect quality results there unless you have a restricted input already.
- You can't pass any class-type objects through an ellipsis, so you need the C-style, NUL-terminated string from the c_str() function.
- If you have multiple vectors where each element corresponds to one element of the other, use a single vector with a struct, it makes your code much clearer.
- Put the end-of-line characters ("\r\n") at the *end*. ;)

Comment: well this worked, but just in junction with the .c_str() 
Thanks very much

Comment: Glad I could help, @FranciscoMatias. I'm actually surprised that the compiler didn't tell you, because passing any class object through an ellipsis is incorrect - maybe you deactivated the according warning?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot (or at least should not) format a `std::string` using `%s`. Try this:

```
s2.Format( _T("\r\nName: %s"), myclass.name[i].c_str() );
```

and proceed likewise for other `std::string` variables.

Comment: Because of the variadic parameter list of `Format` it can't tell when you've used it wrong. Most of the places where you can't pass a raw `std::string` you'll get an error if you try, but not here.

Comment: I had already tried this, but instead of 1 gibberish character, i have more gibberish characters

Comment: using the .c_str in junction with %hs it finally works. thank you both very much